# Multi-colored table cells - fading effect

Tags: css

Need help creating a table with same multi-colored effect. Deep blue for top cells with fading blue for lower cells. 
[image: multi-colored table]

Comment: apply class for the table-cell and apply different color from css

Answer (score 1):

You could manipulate the css **opacity** property

opacity of  a colour differs from the range 0-1

```
For eg;
Dark
color:#FF0000;
opacity:1;

Light Dark color
color:#FF0000;
opacity:0.5;
```

Answer (score 0):

I could see 6 shades of blue (including white). I believe the selection of shade is based on the value in the cell. To do this, you can choose the shades of blue and create css classes to set the bg color of a table cell to those colors. Then in javascript you can code like, once the page is loaded, you can iterate through the cells in table, and assign the desired class based on the value in the cell.
You should also note that once the color value drops a certain level you need to switch the text color from black to white (you can include this in css classes too)..